# What does it mean that the set of polynomials is dense in $C^0([a,b],R)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

What does it mean that the set of polynomials is dense in $C^0([a,b],R)$

$C^0( [a,b ], R )$ is the set of continuos functions.

As I understand it, for the set of polynomials (call this set $P $) to be dense in $C^0( [a,b ], R )$, we need to have that $\bar P =C^0( [a,b ], R )$.

But then what is the topology of $C^0( [a,b ], R ) $, so that each open set in $C^0( [a,b ], R )$ contains a point in $P $ (ie a polynomial).

Intutively I understand this as that a small perturbation of a function in $C^0( [a,b ], R ) $ makes it equal to a polynomial, but can this be formalized somewhat?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see Wierstrass appoximation theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: The natural topology on the the set of continuous functions if given by the **sup norm**. The polynomials being dense with respect to this topology can just be interpreted as: Every continuous function on that interval can be approximated by polynomials with arbitrary accuracy (with respect to the sup norm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space of continuous real-valued functions on $[a, b]$, denoted $C([a, b], \mathbb{R})$, is equipped with the supremum norm $$\|f\| = \sup\{|f(x)| \mid x \in [a, b]\}.$$ Note, as $f$ is continuous on a compact set, it attains its supremum so in particular, it is finite. This endows $C([a, b], \mathbb{R})$ with the topology of uniform convergence, i.e. $f_n \to f$ with respect to this norm if and only if $f_n \to f$ uniformly.

The correct statement is that the set of real polynomials on $[a, b]$ is dense in $C([a, b], \mathbb{R})$ with respect to the supremum norm. So given any $f \in C([a, b], \mathbb{R})$, there exists a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ with $p_n \to f$ uniformly.

This fact can be proved by using the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem.

Comment: I just realised you used the space $C^0([a, b], \mathbb{R})$. Are you sure this denotes the space of all continuous functions with first derivative (not necessarily continuous)? I've not seen this notation used to denote that space before. Usually $C^0$ means continuous only.

Comment: Even if $C^0([a, b], \mathbb{R})$ denotes the space you are referring to, the result remains the same as $C^0([a, b], \mathbb{R}) \subset C([a, b], \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I believe you are right, they are only assumed to be continuous.